# MySQL -- Multiple Updates In One Statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in `MySQL` that looks like this:

`studentID` `subjectID`  `anotherID`  `anotherID2`, `AnotherID3`, `studentScore`

This table has about `100M` records of students in it.

---

Suppose that I have the following information stored in two `python` lists:

`listStudentIDs` = [1, 123, 33, 5524, 425653]

`listNewScores` = [12.76, 73.2, 83.893, 92.3, 53.6]

Is it possible to have `one query` that will update all `studentScore` fields for all students (whose IDs are in `listStudentIDs`) if, and only if, their score in `listNewScores` is greater than their score currently stored in the database ( `studentScore` )?

Comment: Why can't you make several queries?

Comment: @jsalonen: I can. but it might get to 100M queries, at which point I think performance would be severely degraded. the key here is to get good performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, they are 5 student ids for only 4 scores to update.

If your list of students to update is not to long, then you can have an update in one query like this :

```
UPDATE t_student
SET studentScore = CASE
 WHEN studentID=1    THEN 12.76
 WHEN studentID=123  THEN 73.2
 WHEN studentID=33   THEN 83.893
 WHEN studentID=5524 THEN 92.3
 ELSE studentScore END
WHERE studentID IN (1, 123, 33, 5524, 425653)
```

Nevertheless less you may consider to use a SQL statement including several queries :

```
UPDATE t_student SET studentScore = 12.76  WHERE studentID = 1;
UPDATE t_student SET studentScore = 73.2   WHERE studentID = 123;
UPDATE t_student SET studentScore = 83.893 WHERE studentID = 33;
UPDATE t_student SET studentScore = 92.3   WHERE studentID = 5524;
```

Comment: @Skrol29: thank you, I fixed my example to include 5 scores. Do you think your `CASE` solution would work -- performance wise -- if I have (worst case) 100M such `cases`?

Comment: No, MySQL has a limit query size defined by the option "max_allowed_packet" which is 16 Mo by default. With such amount of items you have to update, you will have a problem of data size management which is usually solved by using a database. In other terms, the best way is to save your couple of id/score in a temporary table and run a simple update query on the student table joined on the temporary table.

Comment: @Skrol29: thank you. Any idea how long things would take in terms of running such a join on 100M records, assuming that `studentIDs` / `studentScore` are indexed ? is it 1[sec]? less?

Comment: What are studentIDs and studentScore ? If they are fields, then studentScore should not be indexed, otherwise updating it would have an heavy cost. The time for updating such a big table with join depends of many things, including the server configuration, the table simplicity, indexes, triggers if any, ... In a good configuration, for 100M (100 million) I would say it would take between 10 sec and 1 min.

Comment: @Skrol29: yes, `StudentId` is a field. I thought of indexing `studentScore` because -- as part of my requirement -- I only want to update `studentScore` if the new score is greater / better. In terms of the data type, `StudentId` is an `int`; `studentScore` is a `float`.

Comment: Having a separated index on studentScore may be useful only if you need somehow to select students by their score rather than by their id. This is not the case when you want to select them by id, and then update them only if the score is greater. Having an index on studentId+studentScore would be useless since studentId is a primary key. IMHO you should drop the index on studentScore and you will save query times when you update scores.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, MySql can't handle this. Otherwise, I'd be using it all the time!

Comment: thanks. can you recommend on any other tools/solutions that can work for this? (I really just care about performance, it is less important to me which tool I actually use to solve the problem)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your two lists into a temporary table (studentID, studentScore).

Then you should be able to run a single query to update the main table accordingly.

```
UPDATE studentTable t1 
JOIN tempTable t2 ON t1.studentID = t2.studentID 
SET t1.studentScore = t2.studentScore WHERE t2.studentScore > t1.studentScore
```

Comment: interesting solution! do you think the updates of the `studentTable` be fast, even if I have 100M records to update (worst case)?

Comment: Honestly, no idea. The update part itself should be pretty quick since it's a fairly simple join operation. On the other hand you have to create the temp table in the first place which might offset the speed gain.